# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tableWidget' in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a QTableWidget that's connected to a database, and I'm trying to set it up so that I can call function when a cell is selected. I'm getting this weird attribute error though in the function I'm calling whenever a cell is selected telling me that "'int' object has no attribute 'tableWidget'" whenever I make a reference to my table. I'm not sure if I'm connecting correctly, but the error shows up whenever I select a cell so I feel like there's a minor mistake somewhere

Output:

IN  HEREE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/selghaza/mufasa2.0/database.py", line 21, in getSelected
    selectedList = self.tableWidget.selectedItems()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tableWidget'

```
def getSelected(self, QTableWidget):
     print("IN  HEREE")
     selectedList = self.tableWidget.selectedItems()

     print("List created")

     print("Length of list = " + str(len(selectedItems())))



     for item in selectedList:
         print("item")

 def loadData(self, QTableWidget):
    self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    connection = sqlite3.connect('employee.db')
    c = connection.cursor()
    data = fetch_all()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)



    i = 0
    self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.tableWidget.setShowGrid(False)


    for row in data:
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(i)
        i += 1
        j = 0
        for x in row:

            if (j == 4):
                break
            if(i == 1):
                self.tableWidget.insertColumn(j)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i-1, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("  " + str(x)))
            j += 1

    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(0, 188)
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(1, 155)
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(2, 255)

    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(3, 45)


    self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); selection-background-color: #353535;")

    self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(getSelected)

    connection.close()
```

Comment: Looks like your methods are functions, so `self` ends up being just the first argument. You need to wrap these in a `class` and instantiate it in order to get the results you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **QTableWidget.cellClicked(int row, int column)**
>
> This signal is emitted whenever a cell in the table is clicked. The
>   row and column specified is the cell that was clicked.

NOTE:
function is returning index of selected row and column, and you are connecting it like:

```
self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(getSelected)
```

what means that you are providing int row, int column to your function getSelected:

```
def getSelected(self, QTableWidget):
```

you are providing into row to self(you have an integer in self) because of that you are getting an error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tableWidget'

When the QTableWidget sees that someone has clicked one of it's cells, it will emit a cellClicked event - which you need to connect to like:

```
self.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.getSelected)
```

and the function getSelected might be something like:

```
def getSelected(self, row, column):
    # row and column was clicked
    item = self.tableWidget.itemAt(row, column)
    item_ = item.text()
```

If you want the number of rows that are fully selected (i.e. as when clicking on a row header):

```
len(self.tableWidget.selectionModel().selectedRows())
```

But if you want rows which just have at least one cell selected:

```
len(set(index.row() for index in self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()))
```